# Работа с Git с разных устройств

Tags: git, github, pycharm, git-commit, commit

У меня есть проект *(в PyCharm)*, который до недавнего времени писал на компьютере и без проблем делал commit'ы в GitHub. Недавно купил MacBook и возникла следующая проблема: не могу запушить, т. к. постоянно возникают ошибки.

---

**При такой комбинации:**

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Commit"
git remote add origin <Ссылка>
git push -u origin main
```

**Ошибка вот такая:**

```
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to '*Ссылка*'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

**В другом случае в терминал надо было вводить юзернейм и пароль...:**

```
git config user.name my-name
git config user.email my-email
```

**.., после чего выводилась следующая ошибка:**

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
```

Пробовал также использовать `git push -f origin main`, но в этом случае все предыдущие commit'ы были удалены и пришлось их восстанавливать.

---

Подскажите пожалуйста в решении моей проблемы, т. е. как с нового устройства сделать commit и как в случае чего опять с компьютера?

Comment: Если вы делаете `git init`, значит вы создаёте новый репозиторий. Но если вы хотите обновить существующий репозиторий на гитхабе, то значит не создавайте новый репозиторий, а сперва скачайте этот самый существующий репозиторий с гитхаба, наверное?

Comment: Собственно, учебник по гиту буквально начинается именно с этого https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-Git-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F#r_git_cloning

Comment: `Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead` - в настройках репозитория на гитхабе получите свой токен и вводите его вместо пароля